# how to automatically run a javascript in console after redirecting to the next page

Tags: javascript, browser, console

i'm trying to automate a login and logout script using javascript, but whenever it logs in, the console code clears up. is there a way to make it run thesame script after login? so that it will be able to logout automatically?

this script logs in but after login, it clears the console so it doesn't see the logout code:

var  login= document.querySelector("button[type='submit']");
login.click();

var logout = document.querySelector("a[href='https://example.com/logout.php']");
logout.click();

Comment: If you keep the user on the same page = you can.
You would need to hide login interface (div?) and un-hide/create content.

Comment: I've created a code snippet for same page mechanism - see my answer.

Comment: You could copy the code to the next page/load it there.
frames, iframes = might be a way...

Answer (score 0):

console always refresh when you move page. so i think it's impossible to do it. if you want to make auto login system. maybe `selenium` or `electron` are the best way to make it.

here is the link that can help.

#selenium use python :
https://www.selenium.dev/

#electron use nodejs :
https://www.electronjs.org/

Comment: i have no experience on selenium and electron, so that can't be achieved with pure javascript in console?

Comment: As far as i know,  you can't

Answer (score 0):

I know you wanted to run function on next page, but, anyways, here's what you could do if you stay on the same page:

```js
function login() {
  document.getElementById("bye").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("login").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("content").style.display="";
  document.getElementById("logout").style.display="";
}

function logout() {
  document.getElementById("bye").style.display="";
  document.getElementById("login").style.display="";
  document.getElementById("content").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("logout").style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<div id="bye" style="display:none">Bye!</div>
<div id="login"><button id="loginBtn" onclick="login()">Login</button></div>
<div id="content" style="display:none">content</div>
<div id="logout" style="display:none"><button id="logoutBtn" onclick="logout()">Logout</button></div>
```

Comment: unfortunately i need it to run on the next page not same page, thanks anyways